# replacing guice 3.0 with 4.0 beta

Tags: java, guice

I see some of the classes from com.google.inject.internal.util like $Map etc are no more available. and I am getting the following errors.

```
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    com.google.inject.internal.util.$Maps
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 29 more
```

Any pointers ?

Comment: a) 4.0 is officially released, non-beta.  Use that.
b) This error is likely due to a guice 3.0 extension being on your classpath still.  What build tool are you using?  What JARs are on your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know why you are getting this error without more information, but I would guess its related to you having an older version of gauva somewhere on your classpath. See this similar [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-517) for details.